# Make jQuery use DOM elements as objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I apologize.  I know what I want to do, but not what I should call it or quite how to ask it, so my googling was unfruitful.

I have some animation I'm using to show/hide text.  I'm trying to wrap it up all nice in an object, but the way I'm doing it, I have to run some calculation code each time, as I don't know which section it is being stored with.

Now, what I hate is that I'm re-running a `calculatePositions(entry);` function on every pass rather than using a saved value.  Trouble is, this will happen on multiple elements so the positions array needs to change.  Is there a way save the positions array to a specific DOM element and just calculate it once?  Can I attach these functions and properties to DOM elements rather than pass in the `entry` object every time?

My code:

```
var theShort = {};

theShort.toggle = function(){
    var positions = new Array;

    function calculatePositions(entry){
        /*
        positions = Nasty calculation code
        */
    }

    function showLong(entry){
        calculatePositions(entry);
        //My toggle code is obviously more complex and uses the positions array.
        //But for simplicity sake, I've omitted it
        $(entry).find('.tsl-theshort').show();
        $(entry).find('.tsl-thelong').hide();
    }

    function showShort(entry){
        calculatePositions(entry);
        $(entry).find('.tsl-theshort').show();
        $(entry).find('.tsl-thelong').hide();
    }

    return {
        init: function (){
            $('.tsl-showLong').click(function(){
                showLong($(this).closest('.entry-content'));
                return false;
            });

            $('.tsl-showShort').click(function(){
                showShort($(this).closest('.entry-content'));
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    theShort.toggle.init();
});
```

Comment: unrelated, but `var positions = new Array;` should be `var positions = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about running the calculation function every time, set up a cache based on the element's id. If each element has a unique ID in the dom, you could do something like

```
var cache = {};

function showLong(entry){
    var id = $(entry).attr('id');
    if(!cache[id])
        cache[id] = calculatePositions(entry);

    //My toggle code is obviously more complex and uses the positions array.
    //But for simplicity sake, I've omitted it
    $(entry).find('.tsl-theshort').show();
    $(entry).find('.tsl-thelong').hide();
}

function showShort(entry){
    var id = $(entry).attr('id');
    if(!cache[id])
        cache[id] = calculatePositions(entry);

    $(entry).find('.tsl-theshort').show();
    $(entry).find('.tsl-thelong').hide();
}
```

Then, when you wish to lookup the calculation of an element,

```
var id = $(element).attr('id');
var calculation = cache[id];
```